# SONOS. Browse test_combinatorial_browse_results_pagination Fails

Tags: sonos

We're seeing a failure with the "Browse test_combinatorial_browse_results_pagination" test:

```
Fail: Index + count should equal total at the end of a container. (expected 50 != actual 85)
```

It seem that the test is not doing the right thing. It makes two requests:

First:

```
  <ns1:getMetadata>
     <ns1:id>browse:own-playlists</ns1:id>
     <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
     <ns1:count>100</ns1:count>
  </ns1:getMetadata>
```

Second:

```
  <ns1:getMetadata>
     <ns1:id>browse:own-playlists</ns1:id>
     <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
     <ns1:count>100</ns1:count>
  </ns1:getMetadata>
```

We since these are both identical requests for the first page of results, we return the same result both times from our SMAPI service:

```
        <index>0</index>
        <count>50</count>
        <total>85</total>
```

And the test complains that index + count != total **at the end of a container**. If the second request did the right thing and requested the second page:

```
  <ns1:getMetadata>
     <ns1:id>browse:own-playlists</ns1:id>
     <ns1:index>50</ns1:index>
     <ns1:count>100</ns1:count>
  </ns1:getMetadata>
```

Then we would return

```
        <index>50</index>
        <count>35</count>
        <total>85</total>
```

And, index + count = total, would be true.

The test seems to be doing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's because the test is asking for 100 items (`<count>100</count>`) but you're only returning 50, while telling the test that there are a total of 85. Try returning all 85 at a time.